# Eclipse E4 application does not start on Mac case-sensitive drive

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

We have developed an Eclipse E4 application. It runs perfectly on Windows and Linux. It also runs fine on Mac when the application is deployed on case-insensitive drive. However, when we try to install it on a case-sensitive drive on a Mac the application doesn't start displaying "Unable to find companion library" message.

We have checked installations on both drives and verified that they are identical - one works and another doesn't. So there must be some Eclipse issue related to the case sensitivity of the drive. Note that the issue is unlikely to be in our code since the application doesn't even start.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Could be [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=505409)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was indeed the problem. Once the eclipse folder was renamed to Eclipse and references to this folder in the ini file have been renamed as well, the application ran!